# DoesNotExist during clean()

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models in my Django app:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    ...various attributes...

class Booking(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(
        Property
    )
    ...more attributes...
```

I implemented the `clean()` method for `Booking` which checks various constraints of a `Booking`. A number of these constraints depend on the association of `Booking` and `Property` being in place. For that reason I have the following in the clean() method of `Booking`:

```
if self.property is not None:
    ...Property related validations...
```

Upon entering a new booking in the admin application and just pressing the Save button without entering anything, this generates a `DoesNotExist exception` on `self.property is not None`. It's my understanding that the missing association should be captured by the individual field validation of Django.

When I comment out the `clean()` method the above doesn't happen and the missing association is properly flagged as an error when I submit a blank booking form.

I'm obviously missing something but haven't got a clue what...

Comment: Have you tried changing your conditional to `if hasattr(self, 'property') and self.property is not None`?

Comment: @mVChr Thanks, that solved it. I must say, a very subtle solution and to be honest the reasoning behind it escapes me. Is this specific Django or Python?? If you want, add it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer since it was the answer:

> Have you tried changing your conditional to:
>
> `if hasattr(self, 'property') and self.property is not None`

I'm not sure of the root cause since I deduced the solution based on the error message. I imagine that the Django ORM might create the foreign key association dynamically upon save, so even though it's a required attribute it hasn't been created yet since the Booking instance is new and hasn't been saved.

Comment: So every time I use a fk field for validation in the `Model.clean()` method I should use this conditional?